# showInfoWindow can not show info of all markers

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I'm developing an Android application about google map v2. My problem is that I can not show infoWindow of all marker that had been added.

Here's my code :

```
//define my Marker[] marker;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        // add my Marker[]
                     marker[i].showInfoWindow();
                }
            }
```

When I run my app. Only one marker showed on screen.

I don't know how to solve it. Please help me! 
Thank everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of showing info windows.

http://androidfreakers.blogspot.in/2013/08/display-custom-info-window-with.html

For more doubts please post your code where you adding markers.